# Wordpress Fullscreen site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fullscreen

I'm using the theme IsleMag. How to set full screen site? There are margins now. 
Site: https://namedycyne.net.pl/

Comment: Remove the `boxed` class from `wrapper`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your template does not have this option in your options panel use this code in 1280 resolution dpi for full-screen site

copy this code in your CSS file: style.css in template root directory

```css
@media (min-width: 1280px)
#wrapper.boxed, #wrapper.boxed-long, .boxed .sticky-menu.fixed .container, .boxed-long .sticky-menu.fixed .container, .boxed .sticky-menu.fixed .container-fluid, .boxed-long .sticky-menu.fixed .container-fluid, .boxed #header.sticky-menu.fixed .navbar-transparent, .boxed-long #header.sticky-menu.fixed .navbar-transparent {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not work

Comment: How did you use this code?

Comment: after use this code may your site cache in your browser 
refresh with ctrl + f5

Comment: I add to style.css. I delete boxed class from wrapper and it works. Thanks for help

Comment: Stir the answer tick. good luck